# Import 3rd party libraries in GAE with setup.py requirements

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urbanairship.com

How do you install a third party library that has other dependencies? I am trying to import Urban Airship into my python based Google App Engine project. I understand that the basic premise is that I do something like

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')
from urbanairship import *
```

So I cloned urbanairship from their GitHub account. As an aside, the folder urbanairship actual is under another folder which was originally python-library. Through my several attempts at getting this working I have tried imports like

```
from python-library.urbanairship import *
from python-library.urbanairship import core
from urbanairship import *
from urbanairship import core
```

and then tried renaming python-library to pythonlibrary

```
from pythonlibrary.urbanairship import *
from pythonlibrary.urbanairship import core
```

A more core issue is that urbanairship has a setup process which installs other dependency libraries. So I ran:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

That installed the requests dependency on my local machine which wasn't available in GAE, so I cloned the Requests package from Github also which had its own setup.py file to install more dependencies. Things still didn't work and I thought - this can't be the right way to do this which is why I'm not reaching out to SO for help. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to copy the packages to your root directory (alongside `app.yaml`), which will put them in the global namespace for your app, and thus make them available in your code as if they were installed in the system.

As far as I can tell, in your case, you only need to copy the `urbanairship` and `requests` folder/package, and then import them as usual. If some other requirement arises, just rinse & repeat.

Just to make it clear, the rest of the code you see on the github repo includes docs, tests, and other files to make setup work properly, but you're only interested in the folder (urbanairship, requests) itself.